# Can I transfer clan leadership?

Tags: star-wars-commander

I am the leader of my squad, but my hubby is a lot more active.

Can I make him the leader, without actually leaving?

Answer (score 2):

I looked online and there honestly doesn't seem to be a way to transfer leadership without leaving. But what I DO know is that when you leave, the squad looks for the person with the highest trophy count and makes them leader, so your "hubby" just has to have the most trophies there and you leave and boom, he's leader. But back to your original question, no, there isn't a known way to promote another to leader without leaving.